# XAML element fill all remaining space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application and I'm trying to get the elements positioned correctly. There are just four elements, so it should be pretty straight-forward, but I just can't get it working.

One wrinkle is that the window resizes itself to (about) the size of the desktop window when it appears, so it doesn't have a fixed size.

The elements are supposed to be stacked from top to bottom, so a Stack Panel seemed natural. But The third element has to take up all the remaining space that the top two and bottom ones don't. No matter what I tried, it either took up too much space, or too little. I could only seem to get it working if I gave it a concrete pixel size which, as explained above, won't work.

The latest thing I've tried is a Dock Panel. While it looks correct in the Visual Studio designer, when executed, the third element--a Canvas--completely covers the bottom element.

My XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btnClose" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="X" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="Black" 
            Foreground="White" Click="btnClose_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblTitle" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="My Title" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" 
           Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22"/>

    <Label x:Name="lblControls" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Placeholder" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" 
           Height="Auto" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22"/>

    <Border x:Name="CanvasBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" >
        <Canvas x:Name="cvsChart" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```

Any idea about how to get that Canvas to stretch and fill all the space the other three don't take?

**UPDATE**
Since @Peter Duniho pretty much proved to me that the code worked, I tried an experiment and removed the resizing code I have in place for when the window appears. Taking it out, the window appears absolutely correctly. This is what I do to resize it to (mostly) the desktop size:

```
public const int WINDOW_OFFSET = 10;
...

int screenWidth = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
int screenHeight = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

// center this window in desktop
Width = screenWidth - WINDOW_OFFSET;
Height = screenHeight - WINDOW_OFFSET;
Left = WINDOW_OFFSET/2;
Top = WINDOW_OFFSET/2;
```

So I did some poking around, and found a comment here on the 'Stack that said to get the WorkArea instead of the PrimaryScreenHeight. I tried that and *voila!*, the whole application window appears.

```
int screenWidth = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
int screenHeight = (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
```

As it turns out, the bottom row **was** displaying, I just couldn't see it because it appeared *below* the bottom of the screen. Now I can see it, and I'm back to development heaven!

Thanks to everyone for their input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of possible approaches to this. One of the most straightforward is to contain your elements in a `Grid` and set all but the third row height to `Auto`:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="X" Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="Black" 
            Foreground="White" Click="btnClose_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Content="My Title" Grid.Row="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" 
           Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22"/>

    <Label x:Name="lblControls" Content="Placeholder" Grid.Row="3"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" 
           Height="Auto" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="22"/>

    <Border x:Name="CanvasBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Row="2">
      <Canvas x:Name="cvsChart" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
      </Canvas>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
```

The default setting for a grid's row definition height is `"*"`, which says to distribute all of the remaining space among all the rows with that setting. With only one row using that setting, it gets all of the leftover space.

This produces a window that looks like this:

[image: four row grid with border and canvas filling the third row]

(I set the window background to `Gray` so that your white text and border would be visible.)

<s>Another option would in fact be to use `DockPanel`. It appears to me that the main problem in your attempt is that you set the `lblControls` element to `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` when it should be `Top` instead. When I change it to `Top`, it seems to work fine for me.</s>

Based on your comment below, it seems you actually did want `lblControls` to be set to `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`, and in fact the code you posted seems to also do what you want. It's not clear to me what is different from what the code you posted does and what you want it to do. It would be better if you would provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither approach worked. The Border and Canvas are supposed to appear in the middle of the window. From what I understand, adding it last and not giving it a docking position should have done that. When I set `lblControls` to Top, they appear at the top, above the Border and Canvas, as they're told to, not as they're supposed to. The Grid approach didn't work either. I gave all the Rows a Height of `Auto`, except the Border and Canvas, which I gave a `"*"`. It hides the bottom label as well.

Comment: @Frecklefoot: _"The Border and Canvas are supposed to appear in the middle of the window"_ -- sorry, your question was not clear about the intended result. The code you posted _does_ do that, placing the `lblControls` at the bottom like you had specified, and the `CanvasBorder`, with the `cvsChart` within, between the `lblTitle` and `lblControls`. I can edit the `Grid` example to match your comment, but ultimately it's not clear why the code you have in your question doesn't do what you want. It seems to me that it does, based on your comment here.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my original question. I was afraid that might be a problem, since I placed the Border and Canvas last. I must be doing something else wrong then, because I still get the bottom label being completely covered by the Border and Canvas. At least I assume that's what's happening, because I don't see it at all when I run it. But my application doesn't do anything yet except appear.

Comment: I just now took out the resizing of the window appears, and it does work. So the resizing of the window must be messing it up somehow. So that's where my problem lays. Thanks for all the help. I'm marking your input as the answer as it prompted me to really find out where the problem is...

Comment: @Freckle: Okay, glad it was a least a little help. Keep in mind that the contents of the canvas are not clipped to the canvas. That is, the canvas can be laid out according to the grid or dock panel, but if something is inside the canvas that is larger than that layout, it will cover whatever's laid out below the canvas. If you want help with the resizing behavior, please post a new question with a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and a precise explanation of what the code does and what you want it to do instead. Consider using screenshots to show specifically these details.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the vertical alignment of the Canvas

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't make a difference.